# C function for printing the position of an element in an array not working

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic, allocation

I am trying to print out the scalar product of two vectors, the value and the position of the max element in each vector, and the value and the position of the min element in each vector. However my function for finding the minimum value and the position of the minimum value is not working and I am not sure why since it uses the same syntax as my function for finding the maximum value and the position of the maximum value and it prints the correct numbers. This is what my code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double findingmax(double *arr, int n){
    int max = arr[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i] > max){
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int findingmaxpos(double *arr, int n){
    int max = arr[0];
    int pos;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i] > max){
            max = arr[i];
            pos = i;
        } 
    }
    return pos;
} 

double findingmin(double *arr, int n){
    int min = arr[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i] < min){
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int findingminpos(double *arr, int n){
    int min = arr[0];
    int pos;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i] < min){
            min = arr[i];
            pos = i; 
        }
    }
    return pos; 
} 

double scalarproduct(double *v, double *w, int n){
    double vw[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        vw[i] = (v[i] * w[i]); 
    }
    double scalprod = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scalprod += vw[i];
    }
    return scalprod;
}
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    double *v; 
    v = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    double *w;
    w = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%lf", &v[i]);       
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%lf", &w[i]);
    }
    printf("Scalar product=%lf\n", scalarproduct(v, w, n));
    printf("The smallest = %lf\n", findingmin(v, n));
    printf("Position of the smallest = %d\n", findingminpos(v, n));
    printf("The largest = %lf\n", findingmax(v, n));
    printf("Position of the largest = %d\n", findingmaxpos(v, n));
    printf("The smallest = %lf\n", findingmin(w, n));
    printf("Position of the smallest = %d\n", findingminpos(w, n));
    printf("The largest = %lf\n", findingmax(w, n));
    printf("Position of the largest = %d\n", findingmaxpos(w, n));
    return 0; 
}
```

The input is this:

```
3
1.1
2.5
3.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
```

The output SHOULD be this:

```
Scalar product=6.600000
The smallest = 1.100000
Position of smallest = 0
The largest = 3.000000
Position of largest = 2
The smallest = 1.000000
Position of smallest = 0
The largest = 1.000000
Position of largest = 0
```

But my output looks like this:

```
Scalar product=6.600000
The smallest = 1.000000
Position of the smallest = 32766
The largest = 3.000000
Position of the largest = 2
The smallest = 1.000000
Position of the smallest = 32766
The largest = 1.000000
Position of the largest = 32766
```

How can I print the correct 'i', the position?

Comment: Your position functions do not work because you do not initialize pos to zero at the start of your seach, so if the smallest is in entry zero, the pos is uninitialized (and set to whatever is on the stack such as 32766)

Comment: In addition, your local variable max and min must be declared as double, otherwise you are comparing ints and doubles, and returning a rounded down value.

Answer (score 0):

Your position functions do not work because you do not initialize pos to zero at the start of your seach, so if the smallest is in entry zero, the pos is uninitialized (and set to whatever is on the stack such as 32766. Initializing pos=0 does the trick.

In addition, you need to change local variables `max` and `min` to `double`, not an `int`. Otherwise, you are comparing ints to doubles, and you get the wrong result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double findingmax(double *arr, int n){
    double max = arr[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i] > max){
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int findingmaxpos(double *arr, int n){
    double max = arr[0];
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i] > max){
            max = arr[i];
            pos = i;
        } 
    }
    return pos;
} 

double findingmin(double *arr, int n){
    double min = arr[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i] < min){
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int findingminpos(double *arr, int n){
    double min = arr[0];
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i] < min){
            min = arr[i];
            pos = i; 
        }
    }
    return pos; 
} 

double scalarproduct(double *v, double *w, int n){
    double vw[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        vw[i] = (v[i] * w[i]); 
    }
    double scalprod = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scalprod += vw[i];
    }
    return scalprod;
}
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    double *v; 
    v = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    double *w;
    w = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%lf", &v[i]);       
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%lf", &w[i]);
    }
    printf("Scalar product=%lf\n", scalarproduct(v, w, n));
    printf("The smallest = %lf\n", findingmin(v, n));
    printf("Position of the smallest = %d\n", findingminpos(v, n));
    printf("The largest = %lf\n", findingmax(v, n));
    printf("Position of the largest = %d\n", findingmaxpos(v, n));
    printf("The smallest = %lf\n", findingmin(w, n));
    printf("Position of the smallest = %d\n", findingminpos(w, n));
    printf("The largest = %lf\n", findingmax(w, n));
    printf("Position of the largest = %d\n", findingmaxpos(w, n));
    return 0; 
}
```

Produces output:

```
Scalar product=6.600000
The smallest = 1.100000
Position of the smallest = 0
The largest = 3.000000
Position of the largest = 2
The smallest = 1.000000
Position of the smallest = 0
The largest = 1.000000
Position of the largest = 0
```